# Clojure - component and names

Tags: clojure, architecture

I am trying to understand Stuart Sierra's [`component`](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component), specifically the *naming convention for the components* in order to structure a Clojure application.

If I look into [`system`](https://github.com/danielsz/system) for instance, I see several components mapped to the `:server` key :

- [aleph](https://github.com/danielsz/system/blob/913f4d6836f9e72cf1df985e04b9c2a7d5cc3ff3/src/system/components/aleph.clj#L9)
- [immutant](https://github.com/danielsz/system/blob/913f4d6836f9e72cf1df985e04b9c2a7d5cc3ff3/src/system/components/immutant_web.clj#L14)

Since both use the same key `:server`, does that mean that I can only use one of them if I use this library ?

Similarly, I use `onyx`. Several components are already defined inside [`onyx system.clj`](https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx/blob/cff4c8cef716326d110feed7aeee3bc79f8ca7b6/src/onyx/system.clj).
Does that mean that some keys are effectively reserved by `onyx` ?

What will happen to the `:port` parameter, which seems to be used by many components in the wild ?

**Questions**

- What is get the difference between the keys used when `assoc`ing in the start method and the keys used in `component/system-map` ?
- Is there a naming convention for those keys, how do we avoid collisions between those keys ?
- In which cases (if any) does it make sense to have several systems and can they run at the same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys in the system map identify specific components (instances) in that system. You can use whatever key you like for whatever component you need.

Keys in a specific component record can be one of three things:

1. a configuration value set up at creation time
2. some internal value that is irrelevant to the user of the component
3. a dependency (which will refer to another component when the system is started)

1 and 2 are generally set up by the component constructor and users do not need care about the actual key used in the record.

Dependencies are configured by setting a mapping on the depending component from the dependency key (3) to the key in the system map referring to the dependancy component. This is done with the `component/using` function and giving it a map of component keys to system-map keys as the second argument. That way you can always map any expected key to any actually used key. You can use the short-hand form of `component/using` with a vector of keys, but only if the keys in the system-map are the same as the keys in the component you're configuring.

I hope that answers the first two questions

The third question I think I'd like to see an example of what you're looking for as a separate post

The last question: yes you can have multiple systems running at the same time. That may or may not make sense depending on what you want to do, but running a test system as well as a development system seems like a fairly obvious setup.

Comment: The part about the component instances keys cleared some fog off my mind. Which one of 1 / 2 / 3 are the keys in my links to system/{aleph, immutant} ? I guess it is (2) and that you mean that I should not care about the keys set in the record, as there is no risk of conflict with other records ?

Comment: As far as I can see there, in both cases the :server key is used as an internal implementation object. Also,  in general I'd expect components that need to have dependencies configured to have the dependency keys clearly documented.